# Storing string datasets in hdf5 with unicode

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, h5py

I am trying to store variable string expressions from a file which contains special characters, like `ø, æ , and å`. Here is my code:

```
import h5py as h5
file = h5.File('deleteme.hdf5','a')
dt = h5.special_dtype(vlen=str)
dset = file.create_dataset("text",(1,),dtype=dt)
dset.attrs[str(1)] = "some text with ø, æ, å"
```

However the text is not stored properly. The data stored contains text:

```
"some text with \37777777703\37777777670, \37777777703\37777777646,\37777777703\37777777645"
```

How can I store the special characters properly? I have tried to follow the guide provided in the documentation here: [Strings in HDF5 - Variable-length UTF-8](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/strings.html#variable-length-utf-8)

**Edit:**

The output was from h5dump. The answer below verified that the characters are properly stored as utf-8.

Comment: The characters look fine when read with Python3 `h5py`.  I do see the your codes with `h5dump`.

Comment: `h5dump` also shows that the `DATATYPE` of that string is `CSET H5T_CSET_UTF8;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py as h5
file = h5.File('deleteme.hdf5','w')
dt = h5.special_dtype(vlen=str)
dset = file.create_dataset("text",(3,),dtype=dt)
dset[:] = 'ø æ å'.split()
dset.attrs["1"] = "some text with ø, æ, å"
file.close()

file = h5.File('deleteme.hdf5','r')
print(file['text'][:])
print(file['text'].attrs["1"])
file.close()
```

I see:

```
$ python3 stack44661467.py 
['ø' 'æ' 'å']
some text with ø, æ, å
```

That is `h5py` does see/interpret the strings as unicode - writing and reading.

With the dump utility:

```
$ h5dump deleteme.hdf5 
HDF5 "deleteme.hdf5" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "text" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
         STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
         STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
         CSET H5T_CSET_UTF8;
         CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
      }
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 3 ) / ( 3 ) }
      DATA {
      (0): "\37777777703\37777777670", "\37777777703\37777777646",
      (2): "\37777777703\37777777645"
      }
      ATTRIBUTE "1" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
            STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
            STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
            CSET H5T_CSET_UTF8;
            CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
         }
         DATASPACE  SCALAR
         DATA {
         (0): "some text with \37777777703\37777777670, \37777777703\37777777646, \37777777703\37777777645"
         }
      }
   }
}
}
```

Note that in both case the `datatype` is marked `UTF8`

```
     DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
         STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
         STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
         CSET H5T_CSET_UTF8;
         CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
      }
```

That's what the docs say:

http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/strings.html#variable-length-utf-8

> They can store any character a Python unicode string can store, with the exception of NULLs. In the file these are created as variable-length strings with character set H5T_CSET_UTF8.

Let `h5py` (or other reader) worry about interpreting `\37777777703\37777777670` as the proper unicode character.

Answer (score 1):

You should try storing your data in UTF-8 format by doing the following:

To encode in utf-8 format (before storingwith h5py) do:

```
u"æ".encode("utf-8")
```

which returns:

```
'\xc3\xa6'
```

Then to decode you could use the string decode like this:

```
'\xc3\xa6'.decode("utf-8")
```

which would return:

```
æ
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

When you open files and you want them to be in utf-8, you can use the encoding parameter on the read file method:

```
f = open(fname, encoding="utf-8")
```

This should help properly encoding the original file.

Source: [python-notes](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html)

Comment: I am reading the text from a file which contains these characters, and thereupon storing the text. Using your method, I would have to either alter the file itself, or do this on the fly by checking every character that is read.

Comment: When I use this `encode` `h5dump` shows the same string, but marks it as `CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;`

Comment: Hmm. Sorry you're absolutely right I didn't reread the question after it was edited. I'll do some more searching and try to find something, but I think your solution will have something to do with encoding to utf-8!

Comment: I added a postscriptum to the answer. Does this work? I'm curious to see how to solve this issue.

Comment: The answer chosen verified that the text was being stored as utf-8. I updated my question to verify that I used h5dump to produce the output.