# Storing tuple containing multidimensional numpy array and 1-D list to HDF5

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, hdf5

I'm attempting the following:

```
    SPECIAL_TYPE = np.dtype([("arr", h5py.special_dtype(vlen=np.uint8)),
                                 ("int1", np.uint8),
                                 ("str", h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)),
                                 ("int2", np.uint8),
                                 ("int3", np.uint8),
                                 ("list", h5py.special_dtype(vlen=np.uint8)),
                                 ("int4", np.uint8)])
    db = f.create_dataset("db", (1,1), chunks=True, maxshape=(None, 1), dtype=SPECIAL_TYPE)

    db.resize((N,1))

    for i, idx in enumerate(range(N)):
        arr = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=np.uint8)

        db[i] = (arr,i, 'a', i, i, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], i)
```

The code above fails for me because of the multidimensional array and the list elements of the tuple.

At best, it seems it only stores the first row of the array in the tuple (can't seem to fix this) while throwing an error when trying to store the list in the tuple.

Is there something I'm missing that would allow storing a list of tuples in this manner to work?

NOTE: I've come across these discussions:

1) https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/876

2) [Inexplicable behavior when using vlen with h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543791/inexplicable-behavior-when-using-vlen-with-h5py)

and suspect that it's not possible to directly store the tuple as I would like (mainly due to the `vlen` potentially only working with 1-D arrays?).

Forgive any ignorance in this question...I'm a novice at HDF5.

Thanks!

Comment: Why isn't `list` field `vlen`?  I haven't played with `vlen` much except for the linked answer (and maybe 1 or 2 newer), but I think the resulting dtype has to be compatible with both numpy and hdf5.

Comment: You're correct.  I originally had that and I've updated the code.  The code you caught was just a product of my desperate debugging :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your dtype I can create an array:

```
In [37]: np.array([_],dtype=SPECIAL_TYPE)
Out[37]: 
array([ (array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8), 1, 'a', 1, 1, list([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]), 1)],
      dtype=[('arr', 'O'), ('int1', 'u1'), ('str', 'O'), ('int2', 'u1'), ('int3', 'u1'), ('list', 'O'), ('int4', 'u1')])
```

But trying to create `dataset` with it, even 1d, dumps me out of the interpreter:

```
In [38]: f=h5py.File('vlentest.h5','w')
In [39]: db = f.create_dataset('db',(10,), dtype=SPECIAL_TYPE)
In [40]: db[:]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

There two issues - does `vlen` work in a 2d array, and does it work in a compound dtype? You are pushing the bounds with multiple vlen in a dtype in a 2d array.

Have you seen documentation or examples using `vlen` in a compound dtype?

Notice how `h5py` implements the `vlen` in numpy - it defines those fields a 'O' object dtype.  That stores a pointer in the array, not the variable length object itself.  Normally object dtype arrays cannot be saved with `h5py`. But these fields must has some added annotation that `h5py` uses to translate the pointer into the kind of structure that `HDF5` accepts.

[Storing string datasets in hdf5 with unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661467/storing-string-datasets-in-hdf5-with-unicode) explores how a vlen str is stored.

[Storing multidimensional variable length array with h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658438/storing-multidimensional-variable-length-array-with-h5py)

---

Experimenting, stating with something small

```
In [14]: f = h5py.File('temp.h5')

In [15]: db1 = f.create_dataset('db1',(5,), dtype=dt1)
In [16]: db2 = f.create_dataset('db2',(5,), dtype=dt2)
In [17]: db1[:]
Out[17]: 
array([('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',)],
      dtype=[('str', 'O')])
In [18]: db2[:]
Out[18]: 
array([('', 0), ('', 0), ('', 0), ('', 0), ('', 0)],
      dtype=[('str', 'O'), ('int4', '<i4')])
```

Setting some `db1` values:

```
In [24]: db1[0]=('a',)
In [25]: db1[1]=('ab',)
In [26]: db1[:]
Out[26]: 
array([('a',), ('ab',), ('',), ('',), ('',)],
      dtype=[('str', 'O')])
```

`db2` works the same way:

```
In [30]: db2[0]=('abc',10)
In [31]: db2[1]=('abcde',6)
In [32]: db2[:]
Out[32]: 
array([('abc', 10), ('abcde',  6), ('',  0), ('',  0), ('',  0)],
      dtype=[('str', 'O'), ('int4', '<i4')])
```

2 vlen strings also work:

```
In [34]: dt3 = np.dtype([("str1", h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)),("str2", h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str))])

In [35]: db3 = f.create_dataset('db3',(3,), dtype=dt3)
In [36]: db3[:]
Out[36]: 
array([('', ''), ('', ''), ('', '')],
      dtype=[('str1', 'O'), ('str2', 'O')])
In [37]: db3[0] = ('abc','defg')
In [38]: db3[1] = ('abcd','de')
In [39]: db3[:]
Out[39]: 
array([('abc', 'defg'), ('abcd', 'de'), ('', '')],
      dtype=[('str1', 'O'), ('str2', 'O')])
```

and with an array vlen

```
In [41]: dt4 = np.dtype([("str1", h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)),("list", h5py.special_dtype(vlen=np.int))])
In [42]: dt4
Out[42]: dtype([('str1', 'O'), ('list', 'O')])
In [43]: db4 = f.create_dataset('db4',(3,), dtype=dt4)

In [47]: db4[0]=('abcdef',np.arange(5))
In [48]: db4[1]=('abc',np.arange(3))
In [49]: db4[:]
Out[49]: 
array([('abcdef', array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])), ('abc', array([0, 1, 2])),
       ('', array([], dtype=int32))],
      dtype=[('str1', 'O'), ('list', 'O')])
```

but I can't use a `list`

```
In [50]: db4[2]=('abc',[1,2,3,4])
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

`h5py` saves arrays, not lists.  Apparently that applies to these nested values as well.  http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/special.html has examples of setting a `vlen` with a list, but it has first converted to an array.

If I try to save a 2d array, it only writes a 1d

```
In [59]: db4[2]=('abc',np.ones((2,2),int))
In [60]: db4[:]
Out[60]: 
array([('abcdef', array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])), ('abc', array([0, 1, 2])),
       ('abc', array([1, 1]))],
      dtype=[('str1', 'O'), ('list', 'O')])
```

---

This dtype works:

```
In [21]: dt1 = np.dtype([("str1", h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)),('f1',int),("list", h5py.special_dtype(vlen=np.int))])
```

This does the core dump

```
In [30]: dt1 = np.dtype([("f0", h5py.special_dtype(vlen=np.uint8)),('f1',int),("f2", h5py.special_dtype(vlen=np.int))])
```

Is this a vlen `uint8` problem, or a problem with a vlen be first?

Comment: Thanks for the hardwork!  I've performed similar tinkering and find the same results.  Upvoting for your thorough efforts!